# Cannot write Chinese Characters to ANSI files via CStdioFile?

Tags: file, visual-c++, unicode, ansi

I create a Unicode project in VC++ 2008.

Then I write the following codes:

```
    CStdioFile File;

    if (File.Open(_T("F:\\Test.txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::typeText | CFile::shareDenyWrite))
    {
        File.WriteString(_T("你好"));
        File.Close();
    }
```

I think since File.WriteString(_T("你好")) is writing an Unicode string to a file, while CStidoFile is by default in ANSI format. Therefore, the Unicode string will be converted to ANSI string in the current thread codepage(which is Chinese).

However, after I open the text file, I see it is completey empty, nothing is written into the file. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with mode `CFile::typeUnicode` and not `CFile::typeText`.

Comment: I try to use typeUnicode, but the written text file contain unrecognized contents. I try to open the text file under English and Chinese systems. Both cannot display the contents properly.